# Are calls synchronous in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, synchronous

I can't find an answer to this question, sorry if it's a double post. Whenever I search for this, I get AJAX questions. So, are the `first` and `second` calls synchronous:

```
function test() {
    first();
    second();
}
```

?

Comment: The **calls** are synchronous, but the functions can be **asynchronous**, e.g. if `first()` is async, `second()` **could** be completed first. If `first()` is synchronous, than `second()` executes **after** `first()` is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure of not... just try to console.log inside them, an alert between them, and you should see they are synchronous.

They can become like-asynchronous only if the first one is asynchronous also (but it means that it ends before stardting the second).

Following the example provided just after (or synchronously :D) my question, I think it is better this:

```
function first() {
  console.log('1st ');
}

function second() {
  console.log('2nd ');
}

function test() {
  first();
  alert("you see just the first one");
  second();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They a re synchronous as long as the function `first()` and `second()` are not asynchronous within their scope.

But `first()` will be called before `second()` in any case.

You could find that out with a fiddle by logging something to the console with `console.log()`.

```
function first() {
  console.log('1st ');
}

function second() {
  console.log('2nd ');
}

function test() {
  first();
  second();
}
// -> 1st 2nd
```